# How can I more effectively find the (n)th monthly occurrence of a given weekday?

Tags: python, datetime

For example if I want Saturday, starting with Oct 01, 2019, I need the result to return the monthly occurrence of the last Saturday (09/28/2019); in this case, 4.

This code gives me the desired result but I'd like to find a cleaner way (preferably only using datetime module):

```py
def seq_of_sat():

    newday = today 

    #gets the last Saturday
    while newday.weekday() !=5:
        newday -= timedelta(days=1)

    if (newday.day > 28):
        return 5
    elif (newday.day > 21):
        return 4
    elif (newday.day > 14):
        return 3
    elif (newday.day > 7):
        return 2
    else: return 1
```

Edit:Solution

```py
    shift = (newday.weekday() + 2) % 7
    newday -= timedelta(days=shift)

    return  (int(newday.day) + 6) // 7
```

Comment: I think you can condense the if/else branches into just `return int(math.ceil(newday.day / 7.0))`

Comment: ```(int(newday.day) + 6) // 7``` seems to work for the if/else portion.  Is there an alternative to stepping backwards through each day?

Comment: Yes, something like `shift = (newday.weekday() + 2) % 7` and then `newday -= timedelta(days=shift)`.

Comment: Also, the [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/calendar.html) module might be worth checking.

Comment: @myrmica That did the job right there, thanks!